# Database doesn't exist when reloading the page. Help needed

Tags: database, html, reload, indexeddb

Using HTML5 code, I've created the below database capable to doing create,add,delete and print operations on database.
However, the ObjectStore is created every time i load the html page and the additional values stored isn't present when i reload the page. What is wrong with the code? Please help. Thanks.

```
 <html>
    <title>
    IndexedDB</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB;
    var IDBTransaction = window.IDBTransaction || window.webkitIDBTransaction;
    var db;
    //var test;
    var dbVersion = 1;

    (function () {

    var Cust_Data = [{name: "ABC", email: "abc@gmail.com"}, 
                    {name: "XYZ", email: "xyz@gmail.com"}];

    function initializeDB(){
            alert("At initialize DB function");
            var request = indexedDB.open("Customers",dbVersion);

            request.onerror = function(event){
                write("Database cannot be opened:" + event.target.errorCode);
            };

            request.onsuccess = function(event){
                db = event.target.result;
                if (db.setVersion) {
                    if (db.version != dbVersion) {
                        var req = db.setVersion(dbVersion);
                        req.onerror = db.onerror;
                        req.onsuccess = function () {
                            if(db.objectStoreNames.contains("CustDetails")) {
                                alert("CustDetails store already present!");
                            }
                            else{
                            //alert("Initialize else function");
                            var objectStore = db.createObjectStore("CustDetails",{ Keypath: "AadharNumber", autoIncrement: true });
                            objectStore.createIndex("name", "name",{unique: false});
                            objectStore.createIndex("email", "email",{unique: true});

                            for(i in Cust_Data){
                                objectStore.add(Cust_Data[i]);
                            }
                            }
                        };
                    }
                    else{
                        alert("Not created ObjectStore");   
                    }
                }
            };
    }       

    function contentLoaded(){
        alert("At contentLoaded function");
        initializeDB();
        //db = initializeDB();
        //db = test.indexedDB.db;
        alert("Value of db in contentLoaded function is :" + db);
        var btnAdd = document.getElementById("btnAdd");
        var btnDelete = document.getElementById("btnDelete");
        var btnPrint = document.getElementById("btnPrint");

        btnAdd.addEventListener("click", function(){
                alert("At add function");
                //alert("Value of db in add function is :" + db);
                var name = document.getElementById("txtName").value;
                var email = document.getElementById("txtEmail").value;
                var transaction = db.transaction("CustDetails",IDBTransaction.READ_WRITE);
                //alert("Transaction statement passed");
                var objectStore = transaction.objectStore("CustDetails");
                var request = objectStore.add({name: name, email: email});
                request.onsuccess = function(event){
                alert ( "Added to the database");
                document.getElementById("txtName").value = "";
                document.getElementById("txtEmail").value = "";
            };

        },false);

        btnDelete.addEventListener("click", function(){
            //alert("At Delete function");
            //var AadharNumber = document.getElementById("AadharNumber").value;
            var AadharNumber =  parseInt(document.getElementById("AadharNumber").value);
            var transaction = db.transaction("CustDetails",IDBTransaction.READ_WRITE);
            var objectStore = transaction.objectStore("CustDetails");
            var request = objectStore.delete(AadharNumber);
            request.onsuccess = function(event){
                alert( "Aadhar Number: "+ AadharNumber + " deleted from the database");
            };

        },false);

        btnPrint.addEventListener("click", function () {
                        var output = document.getElementById("printOutput");
                        output.textContent = "";
                        var transaction = db.transaction("CustDetails", IDBTransaction.READ_WRITE);
                        var objectStore = transaction.objectStore("CustDetails");
                        var request = objectStore.openCursor();
                        request.onsuccess = function(event) {  
                            var cursor = event.target.result;  
                            if (cursor) {  
                                output.textContent += "Aadhar Number: " + cursor.key + " is " + cursor.value.name + "";
                                cursor.continue();  

                            }  
                            else {  
                                console.log("No more entries!");  
                            }  
                        };  
                    }, false); 
    }

    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", contentLoaded, false); 
    }
    )();

    </script>
    <body><center>
    <div id="container">
        <label for="txtName">
        Name:
        </label>
        <input type="text" id="txtName" name="txtName" />
        <br />
        <label for="txtEmail">
        Email:
        </label>
        <input type="text" id="txtEmail" name="txtEmail" />
        <br />
        <input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="Add Record" />
        <br />
        <label for="AadharNumber">
        ID:
        </label>
        <input type="text" id="AadharNumber" name="txtAadharNumber" />
        <input type="button" id="btnDelete" value="Delete Record" />
        <br />
        <input type="button" id="btnPrint" value="Print Records" />
        <br />
        <output id="printOutput" > </output>
    </div>  
    </center>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

When working with the old version of the spec (setVersion), the version of the database is a string value. This is why the object store gets created every time you load. I would advace you to put the following:

```
if (db.setVersion) {
    if (parseInt(db.version) != dbVersion) {
        // Create the structure
    }
}
```

Note that this implementation only will work in older Firefox and chrome browsers. In the newer versions of the browsers the open method has an onupgradeneeded callback. For more info about it take a look over [here](http://www.kristofdegrave.be/2012/01/indexed-db-defining-your-structure-new.html).

```
function initializeDB(){             
   var request = indexedDB.open("Customers",dbVersion);              
   request.onerror = function(event){ }; 
   request.onsuccess = function(event){ };
   request.onupgradeneeded = function (e){
      if(e.newVersion == dbVersion){
         var db = e.result;
         if(!db.objectStoreNames.contains("CustDetails")) {
             var objectStore = db.createObjectStore("CustDetails",{ Keypath: "AadharNumber", autoIncrement: true });                                     
             objectStore.createIndex("name", "name",{unique: false});                                 
             objectStore.createIndex("email", "email",{unique: true});

             // ....    
         }
      }
   };
```

Comment: Hey Kris thanks it worked! But i'm getting an error as, "Uncaught Error: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM IDBDatabase Exception 3" at the line, "var transaction = db.transaction("CustDetails", IDBTransaction.READ_WRITE);" in Print button event. The "if (parseInt(db.version != dbVersion)) {" condition is failing.Why is it?

Comment: You need to define your scope of object stores in an array. var transaction = db.transaction(["CustDetails"]); btw when you are only reading data, you can open the transaction in READ_ONLY. The "if (parseInt(db.version != dbVersion)) {" condition is failing. --> your brackets are on the wrong place: "if (parseInt(db.version) != dbVersion) {".

Comment: Thanks Kris for the reply. Oh bad. I put the brackets as you mentioned, but now even though after reloading it is still creating the objectStore which was my initial problem. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Have you taken a look what the current database version is?

Comment: I've defined dbVersion as "1" but after giving the "alert("Present db.version is " + db.version + "");", the db.version value is blank. Also, the "if(db.objectStoreNames.contains("CustDetails"))" condition inside "if (parseInt(db.version) != dbVersion)" condition is failing and entering into else loop to create objectStore when i reload the page.

Comment: If the version of the db is blank, that means that it is a newly created database. I think you will have to work with the onupgradeneeded event instead of the set version

Comment: Could you please help me on the code regarding onupgradedneeded event?

Comment: I've written the code but the onupgradeneeded event is not triggered at all. My initilizeDB() code is as below:function initializeDB(){
 var request = indexedDB.open("Customers", dbVersion);
 request.onsuccess = function(event){
  alert("Database opened successfully");
 };
 
 request.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {//Create objectStore structure.
 };
}

Comment: I editted my response with the code it should. If you don't enter the onupgradeneeded event, then something must go wrong when creating your database. Try adding a try catch to identify the problem

Comment: I tried with your code and when i click Print button i'm getting this error,"108/023427:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'transaction' of undefined," source: file:///usr/local/bin/webkitGl/test.html(88)" and line 88 is "var transaction = db.transaction("CustDetails");"

Comment: Kris, all this boils down to onupgradeneeded event not being called and objectStore not being created! What is the solution to this?

Comment: Well looking at your last comment the problem your db variable. Try to check what is in the db variable when you call the print function

Comment: Is it just alert("db value is " + db + ""); that i need to do?

Comment: Well first thing is check if it isn't undefined, second it is good to know what is inside the db variable.